# I have made the image of the attached capture using a Microsoft Word table. How could I get a similar result in Latex? Is it posible overlap boxes?

Tags: tables, fbox, nicematrix

```
\[\boxed{{x_1}\quad {x_2}\quad {x_3}}\quad {x_4}\quad \boxed{{x_5}\quad {x_6}\quad {x_7}}\quad  \cdots \]
```

[image]

I have made the image of the attached capture using a Microsoft Word table. How could I get a similar result in Latex? I have tried it with overlapping tables and boxes, but I have not got the desired result ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A bunch of boxes and moving around in LaTeX can get you there. Probably a graphics approach would be more easily readable in terms of the code.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\[
  \newcommand{\largestrut}{\rule[-.8\baselineskip]{0pt}{2\baselineskip}}%
  \newcommand{\smallstrut}{\rule[-.5\baselineskip]{0pt}{1.4\baselineskip}}%
  \rlap{%
    \fcolorbox{black}{black!15}{%
      \largestrut$x_1 \quad x_2 \quad \phantom{x_3}$%
    }%
    \hspace{\dimexpr-\fboxrule-\fboxsep}%
    $\quad \phantom{x_4} \quad$%
    \hspace{\dimexpr-\fboxrule-\fboxsep}%
    \fcolorbox{black}{black!15}{%
      \largestrut$\phantom{x_5} \quad x_6 \quad \phantom{x_7}$%
    }%
  }%
  \setlength{\fboxrule}{1.5\fboxrule}%
  \hspace{\dimexpr0.6666\fboxrule+\fboxsep+1em-\fboxrule-\fboxsep}%
  \phantom{x_1 \quad x_2}
  \fcolorbox{black}{black!30}{%
    \smallstrut $x_3 \quad x_4 \quad x_5$%
  }%
  \hspace{\dimexpr-\fboxrule-\fboxsep}%
  \phantom{\quad x_6 \quad}%
  \hspace{\dimexpr-\fboxrule-\fboxsep}%
  \fcolorbox{black}{black!30}{%
    \smallstrut $x_7 \quad \cdots$%
  }%
\]

% For reference (without the boxes)
\[
  x_1 \quad x_2 \quad x_3 \quad x_4 \quad x_5 \quad x_6 \quad x_7 \quad \cdots
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Werner. The exact result you have reached is amazing to me. It is certainly much easier to insert an image, but I was interested in making some progress in my knowledge of Latex. I think your answer will be useful to many more.

Answer (score 3):

Taking advantage of the PGF/Tikz nodes defined by the `nicematrix` package the code is simpler and easier to maintain.

It consists of a table plus some  lines and colored rectangles.

Will take two compilations the first time.

[image: A]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}   
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor, colortbl}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}        
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.5}   
$\begin{NiceArray}{c cccc cccc c}[
 code-before =\rectanglecolor{black!15}{1-1}{5-4},
 code-before =\rectanglecolor{black!15}{1-6}{5-8},
 code-before =\rectanglecolor{gray!85}{2-4}{4-6},
 code-before =\rectanglecolor{gray!85}{2-8}{4-9},
]
&&&&&&&&&\\ 
&&&&&&&&&\\
& x_1 &  x_2 &  x_3 & x_4 & x_5 & x_6 & x_7 &  \cdots\quad &\\
&&&&&&&&&\\
&&&&&&&&&\\
 \CodeAfter
 \tikz{% 
    \draw[line width=0.7pt] (row-1-|col-1) -- (row-6-|col-1)-- (row-6-|col-5) --(row-5-|col-5);
    \draw[line width=0.7pt] (row-1-|col-1) -- (row-1-|col-5)-- (row-2-|col-5);
    \draw[line width=1.0pt](row-2-|col-4) -- (row-5-|col-4)-- (row-5-|col-7) -- (row-2-|col-7) --cycle;
    \draw[line width=1.0pt](row-2-|col-10) -- (row-2-|col-8)-- (row-5-|col-8) -- (row-5-|col-10);
    \draw[line width=0.7pt](row-2-|col-9) -- (row-1-|col-9)-- (row-1-|col-6) -- (row-2-|col-6);
    \draw[line width=0.7pt](row-5-|col-9) -- (row-6-|col-9)-- (row-6-|col-6) -- (row-5-|col-6);
 }  
\end{NiceArray}$        
\end{document
```